# Nginx Serving Cert For Site Even Though SSL Not On

Tags: nginx, nginx-config

I have been troubleshooting an obscure nginx problem where we have a site correctly serving a cert and establishing a ssl connection on port 443 even though ssl is not explicitly turned on for the port.  Below you can see the configuration for the site, which is listening on port 443 but not using the [ssl directive](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_ssl_module.html#ssl).

```
server {
  listen 443;
  port_in_redirect off;
  server_name xyz.abcd.com;

  # websockets
  proxy_http_version 1.1;
  proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
  proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";

  client_max_body_size                1m;
  proxy_set_header X-Request-Id       $request_id;
  proxy_set_header X-Request-Start    $msec;
  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto  "https";
  proxy_set_header Host               $host;

  location / {
    proxy_pass http://xyz-svc;
  }
}
```

Furthermore, our nginx.conf does not explicitly mention port 443 or ssl, but it does include the path to the cert for abcd.com:

```
http {
..

  ssl_certificate     /etc/ssl/certs/abcd.pem;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/private/abcd.key;

..
}
```

Lastly, if we go to http://abcd.com:443, nginx throws an error saying "The plain HTTP request was sent to HTTPS port."  So, clearly it is interpreting port 443 for this site as a ssl port even though we do not explicitly define that in our configuration.  This behavior is true for both nginx version 1.7.5 and nginx version 1.13.8.

What are possible reasons nginx would correctly establish a ssl connection on port 443 for a site with the appropriate cert if it is never defined in the configuration to do so?

Comment: Use `nginx -T` to ensure that you are looking at the entire configuration. The `ssl on;` statement can also be used to enable `https`. Check the access log to ensure that this is the server you are talking to.

Comment: I'm sure this is the server we're hitting because I see our requests in the access logs but also I modified my /etc/hosts to point the domain directly at it as a test.

When i run nginx -t that just validates that the configuration syntax is correct.

Comment: An uppercase -T yields verbose output.

Comment: Somehow a ssl connection is established on 443 even though ssl is not explicitly turned on for the site and even though the shared nginx.conf never configures a ssl listener.

Comment: Ohh gotcha, cool, didn't know about that option.  The configuration doesn't show anything different from what I manually pieced together.  We have a site with a 443 listener without a ssl directive that somehow establishes ssl connections with clients (browsers, curl, and nmap).

Comment: You have no other `server` blocks with a `listen` directive for port 443? You do not have a frontend (e.g. cloudflare) that maybe terminating the SSL for you?

Comment: Not for that site.  We do have a bunch of sites each with their own respective server 443 blocks though.  Sidenote: for this site in question, dns points directly at the nginx instances and so ssl termination is done there.

Comment: So you have SSL enabled on port 443. I don’t think nginx can half-listen for https connections on a given port. It’s either listening for https or not. Nginx should probably generate a warning, but it can’t turn SSL off for just one server.

Comment: Ohhh interesting!  So if you have one site with:
`server {
  listen 443 ssl;
}`

and 10 sites with:
`server {
  listen 443;
}`

Those 10 will automatically have ssl turned on even though it's not explicitly declared?

Comment: I don’t know for sure. But it makes sense to me. I don’t think it’s possible to be implemented any other way.

Comment: That is an interesting idea that we will test!